# BSOD - flicks on briefly and then windows reboots

Tags: windows, windows-xp

Daughters netbook crashed.  She now gets windows page giving 4 options - start normally, save mode, safe mode with networking, last known good configuration.  On each option the BDOS appears for a split second and then back to windows page.  Is it possible to repair, or is it dead!?

Answer (score 2):

The quickest thing is to try if you have nothing of value on the machine is the recovery CD that came with your machine. If it still fails after this, there could be hardware damage. If it boots fine, there was some sort of corrupt setting.

If you actually want to repair the machine and not do the "carpet bomb" recovery approach, we need to know a bit more about the error.

You can start by pressing F8 the moment the machine starts and choose the option "Do not restart on system failure".

Next time the blue screen comes up, it should stay for a while. please write down the error message and edit your question (then notify me below!) and I am sure you will get more help.

Comment: Boss, you are close but why advise him to even go near the recovery CD at this point?  All that will do is give him an opportunity to accidentally install over his existing OS before he even finds out what the problem actually is.  You are TOTALLY right on the F8 and turning off the "restart on system failure" but for God's sake boot a freaking Hiren' or a Linux Live CD before you go jacking around with the recovery CD.  Murpphy's Law and users do NOT mix well.

Comment: @OGChuckLow I mention if he has nothing of value, I would say that the 1 hour on average it takes to recover will be much faster than finding, burning and using Hiren's or any similar recovery... I would never advise this if there are items you want to recover, but, sometimes, it is just the quickest solution under some circumstances.

Comment: Fair enough.  None of your points are incorrect I just hope he is careful, I have seen users trigger these before realizing for sure it's what they wanted to do.